# Linear model prediction is inconsistent

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I have some bunch of data:

```
df_shuffled = shuffle(df, random_state=123)
X = scale(df_shuffled[df_shuffled.columns[:-1]])
y = df_shuffled["cnt"]
```

Then I learned simple linear model:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regr = LinearRegression()
regr.fit(X, y)
```

I know that I should not use learning sample to verify model, but I just want to chek if I understand how it works or not.

I have good predictions, using the model:

```
regr.predict(X)[:5]
array([ 5454.26166397,  3943.78784705,  2125.27231678,  2967.02153671,
    4474.29945607])
```

This is pretty close to the original data:

```
y[:5]
488    6421
421    3389
91     2252
300    3747
177    4708
Name: cnt, dtype: int64
```

Also, I have coefs:

```
list(zip(df.columns, regr.coef_))
[('season', 570.86663333510262),
 ('yr', 1021.9670828146905),
 ('mnth', -141.30042168132388),
 ('holiday', -86.757534933339258),
 ('weekday', 137.22544688027938),
 ('workingday', 56.39322955869352),
 ('weathersit', -330.23017254975974),
 ('temp', 367.45598306317618),
 ('atemp', 585.57493105545359),
 ('hum', -145.60889630046199),
 ('windspeed(mph)', 12457254171589.174),
 ('windspeed(ms)', -12457254171787.625)]
```

As we know, we can make predictions, using learned model like this:
**y=Xw**, where y is predicted value vector, X is a data matrix, and w is a coef vector(regr.coef_). But whis does not works!

```
np.dot(X, regr.coef_)[:5]
array([  949.90689164,  -560.56692528, -2379.08245555, -1537.33323562,
     -30.05531626])
```

This is completely different from what we have from the .predict method. Why? I don't uderstand...

Answer (score 5):

If I'm not wrong y is not just **Xw** you have to add y_intercept. i.e `y=Xw+b` where `b` is the intercept. Try running

```
np.dot(X, regr.coef_)[:5]+regr.intercept_
```

Comment: Exactly! Thanks a lot, my friend!

Comment: Do accept the answer it helps me as well as the community cheers